# `jz` to RIP-relative memory location produces operand mismatch (GCC)

Tags: gcc, 64-bit

```
.macro alloc_linked_list_item_rdi_rax
        movq $24, %rdi
        call malloc@PLT
        testq %rax, %rax
        leaq 0x1a(%rip), %r10
        jz *%r10  # <=
        movq $0xA, 0x0(%rax)  # void *data
        movq $0x0, 0x8(%rax)  # struct linked_list_item *prev
        movq $0x0, 0x10(%rax) # struct linked_list_item *next
.endm
```

When I try to assemble the following macro (with GCC on GNU/Linux Debian x86-64) the assembler produces `ll.s:86: Error: operand type mismatch for 'jz'` where `ll.s:86` refers to inside this macro, at this specific `jz`.

For this macro I tried to use local labels to manage control flow however it raised the error that I can't have duplicate label names (as I used the macro twice over-all in the program), and so I turned towards jumping with a disposition to the RIP (calculated by using `objdump` and counting the length of the instructions afterwards).

The given assembly worked had I substituted the `jz` for an unconditional `jmp`, as for this I'm confused on why the code I've written doesn't work.

Could anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x86 instruction set only has conditional jumps with immediate operands (which describe an offset relative to the program counter).  Other operands need an unconditional jump instruction.  A simple way to work around this is to invert the sense of the jump and jump over an unconditional jump instruction, like this:

```
        jnz .Lalloc_linked_list_item_rdi_rax.\@
        jmp *%r10
.Lalloc_linked_list_item_rdi_rax.\@:
```

(The funny label name intends to avoid collisions with other labels.)

If I recall correctly, some old assemblers did this automatically, but this became less useful and actually quite confusing when static branch prediction arrived in CPUs because it obscured how the branches were predicted by the CPU.  (But most current x86 CPUs do not rely on static branch prediction that much anymore, it seems, so we are back where we started.)